# What is best value for WP_MEMORY_LIMIT and WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT?

Tags: php, wordpress, memory

I have a VPS server with **4 GB RAM** and a single WP 4.5.3. The website is really big with many custom tables and large queries.

My current memory configuration is:

php.ini

```
memory_limit    512M
```

wpconfig.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

Can I modify any of these settings to increase performance without risking fatal errors during large traffic?

(I also have supercache and cloudflare enabled, my question relates only to memory settings).